# Accessing GPIO pins of i2c expander from user space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I want to know the logic of how to access the gpio pins of I2C expander from user space, is it same step as we done for processor gpio pins, or it (expander gpio pins) need any special procedure

Thanks
shan

Comment: How your gpio expander is interfaced to your processor..?. accordingly you need to write driver to communicate to gpio expander, then you need to use `gpiochip_add` and its supporting structures and methods to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the driver for your chip, the interface is the same. Just make sure to enable `CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS` in your kernel config.